# Not able to run package in goland ide

Tags: go, shared-libraries, goland

I am getting this error:
dyld[62775]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.18.1
Referenced from: 
/Users/priyanshgupta/Library/Caches/JetBrains/GoLand2023.3/tmp/GoLand/___11go_build….. Reason: no LC_RPATH's found

I want to know which rpath is being used here so that I can move my library to that directory. The other possible solution could be to set @rpath using some build config (want to change CGO_LDFLAGS). Can someone please help me in how to do that. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

My go-sdk version: go-1.17.13 (amd)

I am using following goland version:

> GoLand 2023.3.2

Tried using -ldflags "-L " in the build configuration. But this does not work. Also tried to set CGO_LDFLAGS value in env variables, but this also does not work.